# AWS schedule a daily reboot

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to schedule a daily reboot in AWS EC2 instances. 
There is no event to respond to, I just need it to reboot every 24 hours. 
The existing mechanism in AWS needs something to respond to. e.g CPU usage, memory etc. How can I achieve what I need?

I'm using a windows machine (2012 server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do really has nothing to do with AWS, it is a pure windows problem.

This blog post will show you step-by-step how to schedule a reboot:

http://westarinfo.com/information-technology/how-to-set-up-a-scheduled-reboot-on-windows-server-2012/

General task scheduler tutorial: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard

Comment: Can I do this via cmd? Basically I have a script in my repo that runs every config needed when deploying and I want to add this as part of that.

Comment: Yes, you can schedule any task you want; instead of a powershell script you can call a .bat file if you prefer.

Comment: Do you have something to point me at (I can always google, and I've already accepted the answer, just for completeness)? If you do please update your answer.